# UserForm Close Event

Tags: vba, userform

I have a UserForm which is opened and closed in a loop while a condition exists. The users can click several buttons which performs an action. The problem is the unpredictability of users. One of those problems is, users, instead of clicking one of the buttons, clicking the close window button on top of the UserForm which progresses the loop without performing an action.

--- edit---
 
Is there an event with that button with which I can execute code so that I can let it perform the same action as the cancel button on the form itself. I do not need to hide or disable it per se.

Comment: Try googling next time before you ask, this question has been asked and answered literally tens of thousands of times all over the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide close \[X\] button on excel vba userform for my progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153491/hide-close-x-button-on-excel-vba-userform-for-my-progress-bar)

Comment: Thank you @vacip, I tried, perhaps not extensively enough or with the wrong searchwords but I couldn't find it on the SO site. I've slightly altered my question as my preference is to have the button do the same as the cancel button on my form and I do not wish to hide it as the question you've marked it as a duplicate of asked.

Comment: Well, now it is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511903/execute-code-when-form-is-closed-in-vba-excel-2007) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887560/how-to-make-userform-in-excel-vba-remember-password-when-red-x-is-pressed/33888699#33888699) :) But I admit, your question is more to the point now then these.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For example, you can add the macro below to the UserForms code module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "You can't close the dialog like this!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: Thanks @SamGilbert, That does exactly what I needed as now I can point it to the cancel button click event in the module, this has my preference over disabling it.

Comment: I'm using Access 2016, and there is no such Event as QueryClose. I tried entering this code, and the event doesn't fire. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a MsgBox, you can just focus a button:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Close_Button.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDITED:** I discovered a better option:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    ' YOUR CODE HERE (Just copy whatever the close button does)

    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = False
    End If

End Sub
```